# Find all elements whose id begins with a common string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a XSL that created multiple elements with the id of "createdOn" plus a $unique-id

```
Example : createdOnid0xfff5db30
```

I want to find and store these in a variable using JavaScript. I've tried

```
var dates = document.getElementsById(/createdOn/);
```

but that doesn't appear to work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [getElementById() wildcard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4275071/getelementbyid-wildcard)

Answer (score 150, accepted):

Using jQuery you can use the [attr starts with](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) selector:

```
var dates = $('[id^="createdOnid"]');
```

Using modern browsers, you can use the [CSS3 attribute value begins with](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#attribute-substrings) selector along with [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Document.querySelectorAll):

```
var dates = document.querySelectorAll('[id^="createdOnID"]');
```

But for a fallback for old browsers (and without jQuery) you'll need:

```
var dateRE = /^createdOnid/;
var dates=[],els=document.getElementsByTagName('*');
for (var i=els.length;i--;) if (dateRE.test(els[i].id)) dates.push(els[i]);
```

Comment: @Šime I don't know the answer, either for jQuery, W3C specs, or real-world browser behavior. But it can't hurt the functionality :)

Comment: Cool. I made Selenium do that with `self.driver.execute_script("return document.querySelectorAll... ")[0].click()`

Comment: What if the string you're looking foris not hardcoded (stored in a variable)  how can it be used ?

Answer (score 23):

You should have just used simple `CSS` [selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll#Parameters)  together with `JavaScript`'s [`.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) method.

In your case :

```
var idStartsWith = "start"

var items = document.querySelectorAll(`[id^=${idStartsWith}]`);
```

if you want to get the end just change `^` for `$`

```
var idEndsWith = "end"

var items = document.querySelectorAll(`[id$=${idStartsWith}]`);
```

Comment: Thanks! How to do the same, but if id ends with a specific string?

Comment: @smus I have added it to my answer

Answer (score 7):

Because you didn't tag jQuery, and you probably don't need it, my suggestion would be to add a class to these elements when you create them. Then use the getElementsByClassName() function that's built into most browsers. For IE you would need to add something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8472488/803876):

```
if (typeof document.getElementsByClassName!='function') {
    document.getElementsByClassName = function() {
        var elms = document.getElementsByTagName('*');
        var ei = new Array();
        for (i=0;i<elms.length;i++) {
            if (elms[i].getAttribute('class')) {
                ecl = elms[i].getAttribute('class').split(' ');
                for (j=0;j<ecl.length;j++) {
                    if (ecl[j].toLowerCase() == arguments[0].toLowerCase()) {
                        ei.push(elms[i]);
                    }
                }
            } else if (elms[i].className) {
                ecl = elms[i].className.split(' ');
                for (j=0;j<ecl.length;j++) {
                    if (ecl[j].toLowerCase() == arguments[0].toLowerCase()) {
                        ei.push(elms[i]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return ei;
    }
}
```

Comment: Testing the className for a specific class can be easier and faster by creating a regex: `var lookingFor = new RegExp('(?:^|\\s)'+arguments[0]+'(?:\\s|$)'); ... if (lookingFor.test(el.className)){ ... }`

Answer (score 2):

```
function idsLike(str){
    var nodes= document.body.getElementsByTagName('*'),
    L= nodes.length, A= [], temp;
    while(L){
        temp= nodes[--L].id || '';
        if(temp.indexOf(str)== 0) A.push(temp);
    }
    return A;
}

idsLike('createdOn')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
var values = new Array(valueKey_1);
var keys = new Array("nameKey_1");
var form = document.forms[0];
for (var i = 0; i < form.length; i++) {
    name = form.elements[i].name;
    var startName = name.toLowerCase().substring(0, 18);
    if (startName == 'startStringExample') {
    values.push(name.value);
    keys.push(name);
    }
}
```