# Counting number of elements with specific ID pattern

Tags: javascript, count

I would like to use javascript to count all  elements that have ID pattern like:

> "Q"+Number

and return the result into a text field "result".

Say, we have the following example:

```
<div>
    <div id="Q01">
        <p>Some text</p>
    </div>
    <div id="Q02">
        <p>Some text</p>
    </div>
    <div id="Q03">
        <p>Some text</p>
    </div>

        <label for="number">Number of DIVs:</label>
        <input type="number" name="result" id="number">
</div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You forgot to post what you tried.

Comment: Yes, sure. I tried things like var count = document.getElementById("Q"+id).length and other options like that

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find all elements whose id begins with a common string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10111668/find-all-elements-whose-id-begins-with-a-common-string)

Comment: @Roko - yes it IS very close, sorry I missed that one out((

Comment: Alexander - If you use jQuery, always mention that in the question or the tags on the question, so people know they can use jQuery in the answer.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder - thanks I will.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know this has been answered, but here is an improvement on @kei's answer.  Instead of filtering all DOM elements using `$('*')`, first narrow it down to only elements with id starting with a "Q".  Another modification as suggested by @talemyn is to add a `$` to the end of the regex in order to ensure that there are no characters following the digits.

```
$(function () {
    var result = $('[id^=Q]').filter(function () {
        return this.id.match(/Q\d+$/); //regex for the pattern "Q followed by a number"
    }).length;

    $('input[name=result]').val(result);
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/bradleytrager/aM7aP/)

Comment: It might not be necessary, depending on what the actual values will be, but you might want to use `/Q\d+$/` for the regex.  The "starts with" selector will insure that the values start with "Q", but, without the `$` at the end of the regex, you could end up with IDs that have other characters after the numbers.

Answer (score 6):

Use the jQuery [`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) method.

```
$('*').filter(function () {
    return this.id.match(/Q\d+/); //regex for the pattern "Q followed by a number"
}).length;
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tewathia/6LEpS/2/)

Comment: How do you return the result into the text field?

Comment: @Alexander Just set the value of the input tag to the element count. See http://jsfiddle.net/tewathia/6LEpS/3/

Comment: I was trying to use "grep" function.

Comment: @Alexander `$.grep` would have worked too. See http://jsfiddle.net/tewathia/6LEpS/4/

Comment: Same comment as in Bradley Trager's answer . . . you should probably use the `/Q\d+$/` regex, to avoid IDs that have non-digit characters after the numbers, since the pattern stated in the OP only allows for numbers after the "Q".

Answer (score 3):

[***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/dx85w/)

```
document.querySelectorAll('[id^=Q]').length
```

*caveat: `[id^=Q]` includes IDs that start with 'Q' so `id="Question"` will also be included.*

Comment: Specifically, this uses `querySelectorAll`, which accepts CSS selectors and works on modern browsers (including IE8+), and an [attribute starts with selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-substrings).

Comment: "starts with Q" is not the same as  "Q followed by a number"

Comment: @T.J.Crowder. That counts for sure but does not return into the text field.

Comment: @ kei: Code dumps are only slightly useful. Saying **what** you're doing is much, much more useful.

Comment: Dupe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10111668/find-all-elements-whose-id-begins-with-a-common-string