# How to access elements on a web page with IDs that contain a certain string

Tags: javascript

I'm new to javascript and web development so this is a pretty basic question (although I've searched around). I need to access a table which contains many columns one of which contains rows of people's names. In each row the id for the text which holds the person's name is setup like this

```
<span class="PSLONGEDITBOX" id = "MTG_INSTR$2"> JOHN DOE </span> == $0
```

in the next row it's it would be like this

```
<span class="PSLONGEDITBOX" id = "MTG_INSTR$3"> BOB DAVID </span> == $0
```

So in order to iterate through all elements which contain names, is there anyway I could simply iterate over all ids which contain "MTG_INSTR"? If not, how would you approach it?

Also have no idea what that == $0 at the end does

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find all elements whose id begins with a common string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10111668/find-all-elements-whose-id-begins-with-a-common-string)

Comment: Or better yest [Get element by part of Name or ID](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15874630/js-get-element-by-part-of-name-or-id)

Answer (score 1):

Try using [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) with `'span[id^="MTG_INSTR"]'` selector:

```js
var els = document.querySelectorAll('span[id^="MTG_INSTR"]');

console.log(els);
els.forEach(x => console.log(x.innerText));
```

```html
<span class="PSLONGEDITBOX" id = "MTG_INSTR$2"> JOHN DOE </span>
<span class="PSLONGEDITBOX" id = "MTG_INSTR$3"> JOHN DOE </span>
<span class="PSLONGEDITBOX" id = "NMTG_INSTR$2"> JOHN DOE </span>
```

Remember you can also achieve the same result selecting by the class:

```js
var els = document.getElementsByClassName("PSLONGEDITBOX");

console.log(els);

var els = document.querySelectorAll(".PSLONGEDITBOX");

console.log(els);
```

```html
<span class="PSLONGEDITBOX" id = "MTG_INSTR$2"> JOHN DOE </span>
<span class="PSLONGEDITBOX" id = "MTG_INSTR$3"> JOHN DOE </span>
<span class="PSLONGEDITBOX" id = "NMTG_INSTR$2"> JOHN DOE </span>
```

Comment: Doesn't work, I think it's because the text is deep inside a table? 

I also tried getting just a single person's name using 'span[id="MTG_INSTR$1"]' but still els appears to be empty (length 0).

I'm pretty sure the value of document is correct since if I evaluate it in the console it shows me the DOM of the web page (actually spent all of yesterday getting that part to work).