# javascript find an id that contains partial text

Tags: javascript

Environment: Just JavaScript

Is there a way to get an element that contains partial text?

```
<h1 id="test_123_abc">hello world</h1>
```

In this example, can I get the element if all I had was the `test_123` part?

Comment: can't use jquery, would have been nice though

Comment: see this maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8714090/queryselector-wildcard-element-match

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) with [starts with](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)

```js
var elems = document.querySelectorAll("[id^='test_123']")
console.log(elems.length);
```

```html
<h1 id="test_123_abc">hello world</h1>
<h1 id="test_123_def">hello world</h1>
<h1 id="test_123_ghi">hello world</h1>
```

Answer (score 5):

Since you can't use Jquery, `querySelectorAll` is a descent way to go

```
var matchedEle = document.querySelectorAll("[id*='test_123']")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it (without using jQuery) by using **querySelectorAll**.

```
var el = document.querySelectorAll("[id*='test_123']");
```

You can get a clear example of it by going through the following link:
 [Find all elements whose id begins with a common string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10111668/find-all-elements-whose-id-begins-with-a-common-string)