# How to apply class function on id function?

Tags: javascript, html

So I have a task to make function (show/hide) for every paragraph (five of them) and I did like so

```
function btn() {
    var x = document.getElementById('para');
    if (x.style.display == "none") {
        x.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        x.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

For every paragraph I used Id instead of class. Because task said one button per one paragraph.

Now I have a problem how to apply this (color) function for all of them in the same time.

```
function color() {
    bgColorCode = '#' + Math.floor((Math.random() * 999999) + 100000);
    elements = document.getElementByClassName('color');

    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        document.getElementByClassName('color')[i].style.backgroundColor = bgColorCode;
    }
}

//Html
<button onclick = "color()">Color</button>
<button onclick = "btn()">Show/Hide</button>
<p id = "para"> Example 1 </p>

<button onclick = "btn2()">Show/Hide</button>
<p id = "para2"> Example 2 </p>
...
```

Idk how to apply this function "color" to all of my paragraphs because they are under id?

Any solutions?

Comment: include your html

Comment: use jquery's show/hide function instead

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10111668/find-all-elements-whose-id-begins-with-a-common-string

Comment: @NileshJain OP is using vanilla JS - they don't have access to jQuery's functions.

Comment: I just started with html/css/js languages after I learn jquery I will apply it

Comment: @BeginnerAlibi keep on learning vanilla JS - I wish I had. Now all I know is resource-heavy jQuery

Comment: a test you could do, is add a `console.log` or `alert` into the function to see if the function is even firing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add the class `color` to your `para` elements and change the function `getElementByClassName()` to `getElementsByClassName()` (you forgot an s). then your code works. Within the for loop you can use the elements array `elements[i]` instead of another call to the `getElementsByClassName()` function.

```js
function color() {
  bgColorCode = '#' + Math.floor((Math.random() * 999999) + 100000);
  elements = document.getElementsByClassName('color');

  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].style.backgroundColor = bgColorCode;
  }
}

//just slightly modified so it works with multiple paragraphs by making the id a function parameter.
function btn(id) {
  var x = document.getElementById(id);
  if (x.style.display == "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="color()">Color</button>
<button onclick="btn('para')">Show/Hide</button>
<p class="color" id="para">Example 1</p>

<button onclick="btn('para2')">Show/Hide</button>
<p class="color" id="para2">Example 2</p>
```

Comment: @BeginnerAlibi Glad i could help. If this is the best solution for you please accept it as an answer so people know your question is answered. If one of the other answers is better for you then of course accept that one.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is what you want. Tell me if you have doubts.

The function `toggleshow(htmlObj)` selects next element sibling of element which triggered the function with an argument `this` which represent the current HTMLelement and if the value of `style.display` is set to `none`, then it changes it value to `block` else change it to `none`.

see [HTML DOM manipulation](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp)

The second function `color()` takes **advanced parameters** that is `(string)id` of HTML element, and loops through all arguments passed and change bgcolor for every `id`. You can pass many arguments as you want.

see [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments)

`document.querySelector('css selector')` selects first html element using **css selectors**

```js
function toggleshow(htmlObj){
  var par = htmlObj.nextElementSibling;
  if(par.style.display !== 'none'){
    par.style.display = 'none';
  }else{
    par.style.display = 'block';
  }
}

function color(){
  
  bgColorCode = '#' + Math.floor((Math.random() * 999999) + 100000);

  for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
      document.querySelector('#'+arguments[i]).style.backgroundColor = bgColorCode;
  }
}
```

```css
button{
  display:block
}
```

```html
<button onclick = "color('para', 'para2', 'para3', 'para4', 'para5')">Color</button>

<button onclick = "toggleshow(this)">Show/Hide</button>
<p id = "para"> Example 1 </p>

<button onclick = "toggleshow(this)">Show/Hide</button>
<p id = "para2"> Example 2 </p>

<button onclick = "toggleshow(this)">Show/Hide</button>
<p id = "para3"> Example 2 </p>

<button onclick = "toggleshow(this)">Show/Hide</button>
<p id = "para4"> Example 2 </p>

<button onclick = "toggleshow(this)">Show/Hide</button>
<p id = "para5"> Example 2 </p>
```

*sorry for my bad English and spelling mistakes.

Comment: you should explain your code so OP understands the problem and solution rather then just remembers how-to :)

Comment: This one also works, even better so I can understand it, thanks

Comment: I know, I should explain the solutions but I am very bad at explaining things.

Answer (score -1):

A better and more dynamic solutions with JQUERY:

*If you don't know how to use Jquery then you can check Mark Baijens answer.

```js
function btn(e) {
    if ($(e).next().css('display') == "none") {
      $(e).next().show()
      $(e).html("Hide")
    } else {
      $(e).next().hide()
      $(e).html("Show")
    }
}

function color() {
    bgColorCode = '#' + Math.floor((Math.random() * 999999) + 100000);
    //elements = document.getElementByClassName('color');

    $(".para").css("background-color",bgColorCode)
}
```

```html
<div>
<button onclick = "color()">Color</button>
</div>
<hr>
<div id="wrapper">
<button onclick = "btn(this)">Show/Hide</button>
<p class="para"> Example 1 </p>
<hr>
<button onclick = "btn(this)">Show/Hide</button>
<p class="para"> Example 2 </p>
<hr>
<button onclick = "btn(this)">Show/Hide</button>
<p class="para"> Example 3 </p>
<hr>
<button onclick = "btn(this)">Show/Hide</button>
<p class="para"> Example 4 </p>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
```

Comment: question is tagged with JavaScript not jQuery - not everyone wants to use it (and for some good reason)