# How to delete all "hidden" attributes from elements with same prefix using javascript?

Tags: javascript, hidden

Let's say, I've got something like this:

```
<div id="some_id">
    <img src="url1" id="el_id1" hidden>
    <img src="url2" id="el_id2" hidden>
    <img src="url3" id="el_id3" hidden>
</div>
```

And now, I need javascript to delete all this "hidden" attributes. I don't know the exact ids, I just know they all begins with prefixes of "el_id". How can I realize it using pure javascript?

Comment: You only want to remove `hidden` from those specific elements shown?

Answer (score 2):

So use [attribute starts with selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) and [removeAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/removeAttribute)

```js
var elems = document.querySelectorAll('img[id^="el_"][hidden]');
elems.forEach(function(elem) {
  elem.removeAttribute("hidden");
});
```

```css
[hidden] { display: none; }
```

```html
<div id="some_id">
    <img src="url1" id="el_id1" hidden>
    <img src="url2" id="el_id2" hidden>
    <img src="url3" id="el_id3" hidden>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) with a selector that:

- Selects all `<img>` inside `<div>`
- Which have an `id` [starting with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10111668/find-all-elements-whose-id-begins-with-a-common-string) `el_`
- Which have the `hidden` attribute

Remove `hidden` from the found elements using [`removeAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/removeAttribute)

```js
document.querySelectorAll('div > img[id ^= "el_"][hidden]').forEach(e => e.removeAttribute("hidden"));
```

```html
<div id="some_id">
    <img src="url1" id="el_id1" hidden>
    <img src="url2" id="el_id2" hidden>
    <img src="url3" id="el_id3" hidden>
    <img src="url3" id="dontdelete">
</div>
```

Comment: OP never asked to remove elements; they only want to remove the `hidden` attributes.

Comment: Ahh, misread, thank you for commenting @connexo

Comment: `e.hidden = false` would be the more concise way of removing the attribute.